# Regular expression for addition to number

Tags: php, regex

Hy all,
I want to make an export csv from my Virtuemart with CSVI and there I have possibility to override some of my field values with regular expressions.
Some of my field value needs to be like: NUMBER+750

I made an override for this:

```
Find: /(.*)/e
Replace: str_ireplace(',', '.', '\1')+750
```

After exporting I see this:

```
Field value original: 9365
Field value after override: 10115750
```

So it seems, the addition works but it also adds the string "750" after the number.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you pastebin your code please ? Maybe you need a cast.

Comment: What happens if you use `intval(str_ireplace(',', '.', '\1'))+750`

Comment: Don't use the `e` modifier as you should avoid because of depreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be it's first finding a number, adding 750 to it, and then either finding an empty string, adding (*concatenating*) '750' to it, or finding an empty string, converting it to 0 and adding 750 to it. Could you change your code into

```
Find: /(.+)/e
Replace: str_ireplace(',', '.', '\1')+750
```

(Changing the `.*` into `.+`).